# jQueryMobile input types width 100%

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, input, width

How do I set the input types width at 100% in jQueryMobile? Same as the input type button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem overriding jQueryMobile CSS class's.

```
.ui-input-text,    
.ui-select
{
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0.4em 0!important; 
}
```